# Setting values for a multidimensional array undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm currently messing with multi dimensional arrays to store some info that involves multiple joined tables and multiple fields within each. I'm grabbing the data using jQuery.ajax() and using a .each to output it, all that stuff works fine, but now that I'm trying to set the arrays the chrome console is showing up undefined values when from what I can see it should be setting them. The only one that sets is the last pass through the loop.

This is what I've got inside the loop in terms of setting the arrays:

```
    gAuthrequests[gAuthrqcount][1] = [];
    gAuthrequests[gAuthrqcount][1][i] = [];
    gAuthrequests[gAuthrqcount][1][i][0] = val.KRANE_REQUEST_DETAILS_ID;
    gAuthrequests[gAuthrqcount][1][i][1] = comments;
    gAuthrequests[gAuthrqcount][1][i][2] = 0;
    i++;
```

I know the loop works, because it outputs fine, I also used console.log at one point to follow the progress of the array in terms of these lines, and everything looks fine, here's the output:

```
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][0][0]: 63
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][0][1]: No comments
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][0][2]: 0
    KRID: (96) Set var: gAuthrequests[7][1]:
    KRID: (96) Set var: gAuthrequests[7][1][1]:
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][1][0]: 64
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][1][1]: No comments
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][1][2]: 0
    KRID: (96) Set var: gAuthrequests[7][1]:  okr.js:360
    KRID: (96) Set var: gAuthrequests[7][1][2]:
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][2][0]: 65
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][2][1]: No comments
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][2][2]: 0
    KRID: (96) Set var: gAuthrequests[7][1]:
    KRID: (96) Set var: gAuthrequests[7][1][3]:
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][3][0]: 66
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][3][1]: I want access to this this this this this
    KRID: (96) Assign Var: gAuthrequests[7][1][3][2]: 0
```

In this example the only variable that will set is 'gAuthrequests[7][1][3]' (66) the 3 before that are undefined

Comment: I would consider using an object instead of arrays. You'll save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Also you have a syntax error here `gAuthrequests[gAuthrqcount][1]);` See that lonely `)`?

Comment: Oh actually turf that whole line all together that's from the console log output I had, I stripped them out before pasting it on here. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using an array of objects:

before first loop:
        'gRQCount = [];'

before second loop:
'var i = 0;'

in loop:

```
    gAuthrequests[gRQCount][i] = {};
    gAuthrequests[gRQCount][i].krid = krid;
    gAuthrequests[gRQCount][i].krdid = val.KRANE_REQUEST_DETAILS_ID;
    gAuthrequests[gRQCount][i].cylinder = cylinderrecid;
    gAuthrequests[gRQCount][i].comments = comments;
    gAuthrequests[gRQCount][i].status = 0;
    i++
```

Cheers for the suggestion elclanrs